# BindingResolutionException on redirect in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2. I just want to do a simple redirect to a route name `products`. But it is sending me a an error of

```
BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 835:

Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $url ]] in class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
```

My controller looks like

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Product as ProductModel;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse as Redirect;
use App\Repositories\Products as ProductsRepository;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function addProduct(Request $request, Redirect $redirect)
    {
        //do some stuff
       return $redirect->route('products');
    }
}
```

I am doing a simple redirect. I think it is expecting a parameter. But can't resolve. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead:

```
return redirect()->route('products');
```

Comment: Yes, I already manage to work with that. Any way thanks for reply